# Apache Tiles + White spaces in folder path

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm currently working on a project involving Apache Tiles, but ran into the following problem. 
The project folder has (a or multiple) white space(s) in the path name.

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Dropbox\Subfolder\My Projects\GymApp
```

Now, to my surprise, when I use Apache Tiles it tries to load the `tile-definition.xml` from the following location:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Dropbox\Subfolder\My%20Projects\GymApp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\configurations\tile-definition.xml
```

So the problem lies in the part where tool X tries to convert all white spaces to %20 (URL encoding), where tool X being: Windows, Java, Tomcat, Spring or Apache Tiles. Because of this Apache Tiles cannot load the file, since the file does not exist (if I try to open the URL in Windows explorer it gives me the error that the file does not exist, same thing shows up in the console log of my IDE).

As for my question, is it possible to have an Apache Tiles project running in a folder which contains white spaces? If so, how is this done?

Note*: If I change the folder name of `My Projects` to `My_Projects` the project runs without any errors, so I know that the folder path is at fault here.

-- Edit --
I use this code to configure the `tilesConfigurer`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles.xml" />
</bean>
```

-- Edit 2 --
This is what my IDE log shows:

```
DEBUG BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO:154 - File Resource file:/C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Dropbox/Subfolder/My%20Projects/GymApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles.xml at file:/C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Dropbox/Subfolder/My%20Projects/GymApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles.xml not found, continue
DEBUG BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO:154 - File Resource file:/C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Dropbox/Subfolder/My%20Projects/GymApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles_en.xml at file:/C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Dropbox/Subfolder/My%20Projects/GymApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles_en.xml not found, continue
DEBUG TestDispatcherServlet:938 - Could not complete request
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name ''
```

Comment: I get this problem as well. Have you found a way to resolve this?

Comment: @jonasespelita unfortunately no, I 'fixed' it by not using any whitespaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use context-relative paths when specifying your tilesConfigurer bean? Because if you do that, it shouldn't matter if your project folder contains spaces.

I have the following code in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/config/template-definitions.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/config/page-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

...and even if my project folder contains a space, Tiles still finds the definition-xml.

Comment: I added the code I use and the error log of my JUnit + MockMvc tests. Running the same tests with a "proper" project path passes the tests without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread but it wasn't marked as solved and I had a similar problem and maybe this will help other people.

With the Tomcat parallel deploy when you add ##2 to specify the war version, that will be expanded into a folder with the same(including the # chars) and those are escaped to %23 which had the same result -  tiles.xml couldn't be loaded.

To solve this I override the URLApplicationResource class, and in both constructors instead of

```
file = new File(url.getPath());
```

I used

```
file = new File(url.toURI());
```